# Current parameters in url set in the next url in django

Tags: python, django

I have a url like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/?from=&to=&status=1
```

I have an button in that page to export all orders but if i have a status I need to send this as an parameter in that url to filter before export

```
<a href="{% url 'orders:export' %}">Export</a>
```

How can I send parameters to that export function

Comment: Try this: `{% url 'orders:export' from to status %}` and in urls `path('export/<str:from>/<str:to>/<int:status>', views.export_view, name='export')` then in your view `def export_view(request, from, to, status):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply append your query string after url as follows

```
<a href="{% url 'orders:export' %}?from=&to=&status=1">Export</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need to HTML encode the string in the href so:

```
<a href="{% url 'orders:export' %}?from=&amp;to=&amp;status=1">Export</a>
```

if you want to pass values of variables to the parameters, you use the [**`|urlencode`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode):

```
<a href="{% url 'orders:export' %}?from={{ from|urlencode }}&amp;to={{ to|urlencode }}&amp;status={{ status|urlencode }}">Export</a>
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, it is necessary to encode query string, cause I implemented without doing any type of encoding and it works just fine

Comment: @Polymath: imagine that `from` contains `'foo&bar=2'` as value, then you create an invalid extra attribute `bar`, or for example if the item after the `&` is `lt;` then that will be tanslated not as &lt;` but `<`. Usually browsers will leave it an ampersand if they can not match it with an encoded value and encode strange characters, but there is always a change that you end up with an "accidently" match. A lot of software eventually fails because people never anticipate that the values will contain question marks, ampersands, equal signs, double quotes, etc.